# alias constant in the inherited class

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, using-declaration

I have a base class defining a constant and the child class can use it using alias. The construct is as below

```
class Base
{
protected:
    static const int A_ = 1;
};

class Foo : public Base
{
private:
    using Base::A_;
};
```

However, when I define a subclass of `Foo` as

```
class Go : public Foo
{
private:
    using Base::A_;
};
```

the compiler emits the error: `error: ‘const int Base::A_’ is private within this context`. I do not get it since `Base::A_` is protected. What did the compiler see in this case and what can be the solution to use `Base::A_` in `Go` ?

Comment: The compiler sees the private `A_` from `Foo`

Comment: why is it not protected in `Foo` ?

Comment: btw its not an alias. Here `using` just makes the name accessible elsewhere.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the intention is to not make `Foo::A_` accessible to avoid confusion.

Comment: but your intention is to access `A_` in the class derived from `Foo`. Thats what protected is for. The access specifiers are not transitive.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I must admit that making it protected in `Foo` solve the problem. Why don't you make an answer then I will accept it.

Comment: BTW, clang/msvc accept the original code. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ecvK775zY)

Comment: fwiw, I did a bit of reasearch, but I don't understand who is right here. If you do care about which compiler is correct here you might want to add some information about the different results to the question and add a `lanugage-lawyer` tag

Answer (score 0):

> I do not get it since Base::A_ is protected.

`Go` inherits from `Foo` not from `Base`. `A_` is private in `Foo` not protected.

If you want to have access to `A_` in classes derived from `Foo` then `A_` should be `public` or `protected` in `Foo`.

Comment: Seems not as trivial. msvc and clang accept the original code. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ecvK775zY)

Comment: @Jarod42 I admit, I wasnt completely certain about the answer. cppreference only talks about the direct base (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration). I'm afraid a language lawyer is needed

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number so this is yet to be defined in the standard and compiler-dependent?

Comment: @kstn I need to do more research. For now it would be cool if you could unaccept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### tl;dr

- From a strict standards perspective none of the 3 compilers are right.
- Your example should be ill-formed in C++20 (and previous versions), because it violates [9.9 [namespace.udecl] (17)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/namespace.udecl#17):

  > <sup>(17)</sup> [...] The base class members mentioned by a *using-declarator* shall be visible in the scope of at least one of the direct base classes of the class where the *using-declarator* is specified.

  - The commitee also confirmed this rationale in [CWG 1960](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1960):

    > Rationale (November, 2014):
    > The rule was introduced because the hiding of a base class member by an intermediate derived class is potentially intentional and should not be capable of circumvention by a using-declaration in a derived class. The consensus of CWG preferred not to change the restriction.
- ... but in practice none of the 3 major compilers (gcc, clang, msvc) implements this correctly.
- This will most likely be fixed in C++23; The cited paragraph from above will be removed by [P1787](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html), thereby making your example well-formed.

  - The paper also mentions the sad reality of current implementations: [P1787 R6](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html#definitions)

    > CWG1960 (currently closed as NAD) is resolved by removing the rule in question (which is widely ignored by implementations and gives subtle interactions between using-declarations).
- gcc has a name-resolution bug that causes your compiler error: [gcc Bug 19377](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19377)

---

#### 1. Disclaimer

- This post refers only to the C++20 standard; i haven't checked all relevant sections in all previous standards.
- In my examples i'll use both static and non-static data members; the rules regarding using-declarations are the same for both. <sup>1</sup>

1. This does not extend to other class member declarations; notably nested class and enumeration type members ([class.qual 1.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lookup.qual#class.qual-1.4)) and constructors ([class.qual 2.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lookup.qual#class.qual-2.2), [namespace.udecl](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/namespace.udecl))  have a few special rules.

---

#### 2. Long Explanation

The main rule we need to consider to check if your code is well formed is:
[9.9 The using declaration [namespace.udecl] (17)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/namespace.udecl#17)

> <sup>(17)</sup> In a *using-declarator* [...] all members of the set of introduced declarations shall be accessible. [...] In particular, if a derived class uses a *using-declarator* to access a member of a base class, the member name shall be accessible. [...] The base class members mentioned by a *using-declarator* shall be visible in the scope of at least one of the direct base classes of the class where the *using-declarator* is specified.

So there are two checks that a member using-declarator must pass for it to be well-formed:

- The member it refers to must be [accessible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access)
- The member it refers to must be [visible](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/) within a **direct** base class

---

##### 2.1 Pre-reqs

There are a few key concepts we need to cover before we can get to performing those two checks:

###### 2.1.1 Visibility and Accessibility

I'm going to assume familiarity with visibility and accessibility.
Here's a quick definition if required:

- [Accessiblity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access) refers to private, protected, public access control
- [Visibility](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/) refers to name hiding, e.g. in the following example the outer `x` variable is hidden by the inner `x` variable (so within the inner scope the outer `x` variable is NOT visible):

  ```cpp
  {
      int x;
      {
          int x;
      }
  }
  ```

Here's a [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Pe481j5br) that demonstrates all 4 possible combinations of accessibility and visibility for class members.

###### 2.1.2 using-declarators hide members of base classes

Another key concept we need to cover is that using-declarators introduce synonyms - those synonyms are member-declarations and as such can hide members of the same name from base classes.

This is given by [9.9 The using declaration [namespace.udecl]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/namespace.udecl#1)

> <sup>(1)</sup> Each using-declarator in a using-declaration introduces a set of declarations into the declarative region in which the using-declaration appears. [...] [The unqualified-id of the] using-declarator is declared in the declarative region in which the using-declaration appears as a synonym for each declaration introduced by the using-declarator. [...]
> <sup>(2)</sup> Every using-declaration is a declaration and a member-declaration and can therefore be used in a class definition.

and [6.4.10 Name hiding [basic.scope.hiding]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.scope.hiding#1):

> <sup>(1)</sup> A declaration of a name in a nested declarative region hides a declaration of the same name in an enclosing declarative region.

This basically means that `using Base::A_` within `Foo` will create a synonym - `Foo::A_` - that refers to `Base::A_`.
This synonym hides the original `Base::A_` member.

Note that the accessibility of `Base::A_` has not been changed - it is still public - `Base::A_` is just not visible anymore because the synonym `Foo::A_`  hides it within `Foo` and `Go`.

Here's a small example similar to your example: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/P6rWYqY3n)

```cpp
struct Base {
    static const int A_ = 1;
};

struct Foo : Base {
private:
    // this introduces a synonym for Base::A_ which hides Base::A_
    // (only the synonym is visible within Foo and Go)
    using Base::A_;
};

struct Go : Foo {
    int go();
};
```

In this case the following applies:
Within the scope of `Go`:

- `Base::A_` is NOT visible, but it is accessible (hidden by `Foo::A_`)
- `Foo::A_` (the synonym) is visible, but it is NOT accessible

Note that we can't access `A_` within `Go` directly because it would resolve to `Foo::A_` which is not accessible:

```cpp
int Go::go() {
    // resolves to the synonym Foo::A_, which is private in Foo
    // -> ill-formed
    return A_;
}
```

But we can still access `Base::_A` from within `Go` (it is accessible, just not visible) by using a nested-name-specifier: <sup>2</sup>

```cpp
int Go::go() {
    // resolves directly to Base::A_, which is public in Base
    // -> well-formed
    return Base::A_;
}
```

2. This is possible because [nested-name-specifiers](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.id.qual) only consider the [specified class scope](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lookup.qual#class.qual-1), i.e. in this case it'll only look for `A_` in `Base`, but NOT in `Foo`. There's also a mention of this in [class.qual](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lookup#class.qual-3).

---

##### 2.2 So is your example well-formed?

So lets get back to actually checking if your code example is well-formed:

- The member it refers to must be [accessible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access)
- The member it refers to must be [visible](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/) within a **direct** base class

###### 2.2.1 Is `Base::A_` accessible?

using-declarations are resolved using [qualified name lookup](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lookup.qual#class.qual-1), so the name must be resolved within the given class.

[9.9 The using declaration[namespace.udecl]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/namespace.udecl#12)

> <sup>1</sup> [...] The set of declarations introduced by the using-declarator is found by performing qualified name lookup for the name in the using-declarator. [...]

In your case this means that `using Base::A_;` within `Go` must only consider members within `Base` for this check - NOT within `Foo`.

- `Base::A_` is a public member
- `Go` inherits publically from `Foo`, which in turn inherits publically from `Base`

So `Base::A_` **must** be accessible within `Go`.

Note that this is where gcc messes up - instead of only considering members of `Base` it also checks in `Foo` and finds the synonym, which produces the bogus compiler error about `Foo::A_` not being accessible.

This is most likely related to [gcc Bug 19377](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19377).

gcc also doesn't like (some) nested name specifiers; note that if we use the example from above but use a non-static data member then gcc suddenly doesn't like the nested name specifier:

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/686ssfqcW)

```cpp
struct Base {
    int A_ = 1;
};

struct Foo : Base {
private:
    using Base::A_;
};

struct Go : Foo {
    int go() {
        // resolves to the synonym Foo::A_ (which is private)
        // -> ill-formed
        // all 3 compilers agree
        return A_;

        // nested-name-specifier that resolves directly to Base::A_
        // -> well-formed
        // (only gcc wrongly rejects this)
        return Base::A_;

        // same as above, just with explicit this
        // -> well-formed
        // all 3 compilers agree (even gcc, hooray!)
        return (*this).Base::A_;
        return this->Base::A_;
    }
};
```

###### 2.2.2 Is `Base::A_` visible within a direct base class?

Note that is calls for a check of visibility within a **direct** base class - in your case `Go` only inherits from `Foo`, so `Foo` is the only direct base class of `Go`.

As covered above `Base::A_` is NOT visible within `Foo` (it gets hidden by the synonym `Foo::A_`), so this check should fail (and therefore your example should be ill-formed)

However neither gcc, clang nor msvc actually do this check (even though it is clearly mandated by the standard).

So none of those 3 compilers are conforming to the standard in this case.

This has also been covered in a standard defect report: [CWG 1960](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1960)

> The base class members mentioned by a using-declaration shall be visible in the scope of at least one of the direct base classes of the class where the using-declaration is specified.
>
> The rationale for this restriction is not clear and should be reconsidered.
>
> **Rationale (November, 2014):**
> The rule was introduced because the hiding of a base class member by an intermediate derived class is potentially intentional and should not be capable of circumvention by a using-declaration in a derived class. The consensus of CWG preferred not to change the restriction.

which has been resolved in 2014 as NAD (not a defect), i.e. clearly indicating that the standard committee wants your example to be ill-formed.

In case you're interested those are the open compiler bugs in gcc and clang for this: (unresolved for quite some time now)

- gcc: [Bug 32039 - Using declaration accepts non-visible members from base classes](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=32039)
- clang: [Issue 20624 - No diagnostic where using-declaration names entity not found by class member name lookup in any direct base](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/20624)

---

#### 3. C++23 to the rescue!

The paper [P1787R6](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html) will remove the visibility check completely from that paragraph:

> <sup>(17)</sup> In a *using-declarator* that does not name a constructor, <s>all members of the set of introduced</s> [every] declaration[s] [named] shall be accessible.   > In a *using-declarator* that names a constructor, no access check is performed.
> <s>In particular, if a derived class uses a using-declarator to access a member of a base class, the member name shall be accessible. If the name is that of an overloaded member function, then all functions named shall be accessible. The base class members mentioned by a using-declarator shall be visible in the scope of at least one of the direct base classes of the class where the using-declarator is specified.</s>

P1787R6 will most likely be merged into the C++ Standard with C++23.
So in C++23 your example should be well-formed out of the box.

There's even a rationale for the change in that paper:

> CWG1960 (currently closed as NAD) is resolved by removing the rule in question (which is widely ignored by implementations and gives subtle interactions between using-declarations).

---

#### 4. Potential fix for C++ Versions before C++23

A potential way in which you could make your code well-formed before C++23 would be to make `Base` a direct base class of `Go`.

A cheesy way you could accomplish this would be by using virtual inheritance:
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/69E4GM34d)

```cpp
struct Base {
    static const int A_ = 1;
    int B_ = 1;
};

struct Foo : virtual Base {
private:
    using Base::A_;
    using Base::B_;
};

struct Go : Foo, virtual Base {
    using Base::A_;
    using Base::B_;
};
```